# Android Multi-Touch with sliding

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm writing an application for Android that uses two rotary knobs. These two knobs need to be able to be turned at the same time. I'm using the RotaryKnobView class from http://go-lambda.blogspot.com/2012/02/rotary-knob-widget-on-android.html. In my layout, I have two views defined as these, and they are each in a separate LinearLayout with the base layout as a RelativeLayout.

Also, splitMotionEvents is set to "true".

XML:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lknoblayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        android:orientation="horizontal" >
  <com.anndconsulting.sketch.CopyRotaryKnobView
    android:id="@+id/leftknob"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"



    android:background="@drawable/singleknob80"
    android:visibility="visible" />
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/rknoblayout"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:gravity="right"
      android:orientation="horizontal" >

   <com.anndconsulting.sketch.CopyRotaryKnobView
    android:id="@+id/rightknob"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="@drawable/singleknob80"
    android:visibility="visible" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the RotaryKnobView's onTouch ACTION_MOVE method, you are updating the angle by a constant number. This will cause it to update and move no matter what finger moves. Try using a variable based on the touch rather than a constant.